# Почему не работает событие Status, хотя в RasStatus всегда реальный код?

Tags: windows, activex

**Добавлено из комментария**.

В приложении задействован не визуальный Active X компонент - RasDial.ocx. С помощью его я контролирую сетевое подключение. У него одно событие - Status. Оно не происходит при ошибке (смене статуса). Обработчик пришлось сделать через таймер, считывая с-во RasStatus. Не хочется все время "долбить" таймером..

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, приведите код.

Comment: Не понял уже Вашего вопроса. Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Конечно, можно перехватить сообщение WM_RASDIALEVENT, но тогда компонент только избавит от заполнения структур в WIN API